# Is it possible to convert an avi file to mp4 in real time?

Tags: html

I have an AVI file that I would like to be played inside [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org). I understand it uses HTML5 which requires movie files to be converted to MP4/OGV, so I was wondering if there was a framework that exists which will convert an AVI file to an MP4 file in real-time (and without necessarily being stored on the server)

...the more I think about this, the more I'm beginning to think this isn't possible. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: It's probably possible, but probably not practical.  Realtime transcoding would require a lot of processing power.

Comment: Also something I started thinking about. I may just have to change the way my users interact with our platform :(

Answer (score 0):

The video can be transcoded in (sort of) realtime by hardware or even software, but I'ts never a practical aproach since you are spending lot of processing power for each client for each video. This is madness. It's adviceable to cache pages... so videos are needed to be cached.

A simple way is to upload/place the video in a folder in the server, then trigger a transcoding (using FFMPEG) to a file which is the file to be served.